# Expect can not expect the output

Tags: expect

I have problem with my simple code, 
the expect can not expect the output

```
set timeout 10
set user username
set password password
spawn  ssh $user@000.000.000.000
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"
expect eof
send "cv mk ghassan-test-5\r"
sleep 45
expect "ok" { send "cv set ghassan-test-5\r" }
sleep 20
expect -gl "Ok" { send "cv rbset ghassan-test-5\r" }
expect eof
sleep 20
expect -gl "Ok" { send "cv ls\r" }
sleep 10
expect eof`
send "exit\r"
```

the script run and and enter to the remote server
but after `send "cv mk ghassan-test-5\r"` the output is generated, .....
***Please wait while database is writing to disk.
Writing the database file can take minutes...
ok***, but when the script run the next line `expect "ok" { send "cv set ghassan-test-5\r" }` it did not run and did not expect the `ok` since the `ok` but if i expect ***minutes insted of ok*** it work fine (the `ok` appear after 1 minute)

Comment: use private keys instead of passwords, it is **really bad practice** to store a password in a file

Comment: Why are you using `\r` instead of `\n`?

Comment: @terdon, because that's how expect works: `send \r` means "the user pressed the Enter key"

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the script, and expect will show you why it's not matching.